# Unable to get array value using a for loop

Tags: arrays, loops, undefined

I add values into the array like this:

```
ansArray = {question:id[count], answer: 'a'};
```

and the console displays the result like this:

```
(
    {
        answer = a;
        question=1;
    },
    {
        answer =d;
        question=2;
    }
    //......

    //.......
)
```

I used a for loop like this:

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++){
    alert(ansArray[i].answer); //This comes with undefined error
    alert(ansArray[i].question); //undefined
}
```

this comes up with undefined error;

but if i don't use the 'i' variable and use a number instead, the info shows correct value:

```
 alert(ansArray[0].answer); //shows correct value
 alert(ansArray[1].question); //shows correct value
```

why doesn't the for loop shows a error?  What am I missing here?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your ansArray variable is not an array, but an object. You are declaring it like the following:

```
ansArray = {question:id[count], answer: 'a'};
```

This is creating an object with a question field, and an answer field. You can declare objects like this:

```
someObject = {};
```

And you can declare arrays like this:

```
someArray = [];
```

So, you probably mean to have something like this:

```
ansArray = [{question:0, answer:'a'}];
```

This would give you an array containing a single object. I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
var ansArray = [];
ansArray[0] = {question:0, answer:'a'};
ansArray[1] = {question:1, answer:'d'};
...
ansArray[19] = {question:19, answer:'b'};
```

You would be able to loop over this with your original loop code. It would also be helpful to use the javascript tag.